# How to use DraggablePanel in landscape full screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, panel, draggable, drag

Now, I am using https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel

I want to play video and drag video. In the portrait screen, it is easily but in the landscape full screen it is not working as my expection.

You can help me to resolve it. If you have example, you can share it with me.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Show us your effort so far. And again, what is your expectation?

Answer (score 1):

First of all the project is **deprecated**. So don't expect it will work with the latest SDK levels.

Next please go through this [issue](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel/issues/22) already mentioned on GitHub. I believe this is a bug since the issue is marked with the label 'Bug'. So as mentioned in the linked post, there might be some workarounds for it but again they clearly won't work on all Android Versions.